How to pretty print a lua table into an nvim buffer?
Neovim provides a convenient pretty-printer:
:lua vim.print(vim.lsp.get_active_clients())

However, the active lsp clients output is massive so I'd want to see it in a buffer.
With vim-scriptease, I can use :Verbose to capture that output into a buffer:
:Verbose lua vim.print(vim.lsp.get_active_clients())

That pretty prints the table, captures the output, and creates a buffer with that output. Great to use / to navigate around the output.
But it seems that capturing lua should be easier in nvim since it's a core config language.
I figured out a command, but it seems verbose:
:lua vim.api.nvim_put(vim.split(vim.inspect(vim.lsp.get_active_clients()), "\n"), "", true, false)

I expected to find something like vim.api.nvim_as_buffer(vim.lsp.get_active_clients()), but maybe I'm just having trouble finding it in lua.txt?

You could use v:lua:
:new | put =v:lua.vim.inspect(v:lua.vim.lsp.get_active_clients())

(which apparently doesn't work in nvim 0.10 because attached_buffers contains integer indexes (E5100: table should contain either only integer keys or only string keys))
or luaeval():
:new | put =luaeval('vim.inspect(vim.lsp.get_active_clients())')


vim.print echos the string but vim.inspect returns the string, so that might work. Not sure about lua as expressions. Maybe execute('lua vim.inspect(...))?

@idbrii I'd forgotten about v:lua; try that one

In my testing, you need a return in luado: :new | luado return vim.inspect(vim.lsp.get_active_clients()) it will only update the buffer line if the contents are returned

And for the v:lua syntax you also need it for the argument: :new | put =v:lua.vim.inspect(v:lua.vim.lsp.get_active_clients())

If you want to consider execute() then go with luaeval() directly: :new | put =luaeval('vim.inspect(vim.lsp.get_active_clients())')

The v:lua solution doesn't work in nvim 0.10 because attached_buffers contains integer indexes (E5100: table should contain either only integer keys or only string keys), but the luaeval command works!

More caveats with luaeval (on nvim 0.10): It requires single quotes and seems it can't accept any nested double quotes. Otherwise you get "E116: Invalid arguments for function luaeval" or "E115: Missing quote: 'vim.inspect("

I think the command-line parser occasionally mistakes a string expression quote for a comment
